# nginx multiple domains always give just the first domain

Tags: nginx

I need to support multiple domains with one NGINX instance,
but always the first listed domain grabs the request.

For example I have as below.  But when a client requests
beta.com, the nginx server responds with the alpha.com page.

Oh, and I already read the other similar posts and tried
uncommenting

```
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
```

but it did not help.

```
cd /etc/nginx

# ls sites-enabled
   alpha -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/alpha
   beta -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/beta


# cat sites-available/alpha
server {
        listen 80;
        #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html/alpha;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name alpha.com *.alpha.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }

        location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                allow ::1;
                deny all;
        }
}

# cat sites-available/beta 
server {
        listen 80;
        #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html/beta;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name beta.com *.beta.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }

        location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                allow ::1;
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Comment: Just to verify some basics: you've tested your nginx.conf setup by running `nginx -t` with root privileges? You've reloaded the nginx configuration (restart or reload the service) since you made changes? Since you have commented out IPv6, I am assuming the server does not have an IPv6 address?

Comment: # nginx -t
    nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
    nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: Yes I did /etc/init.d/nginx restart; and yes only ipv4.

Comment: Is there anything in the error log? What is in the access log?

Comment: Many many thanks!  Checking the access log I realized I had a typo in beta's server_name line, so it was defaulting to alpha since NO domain matched.  Thank you for the key!

Comment: It is that reason I debate whether or not to copy and paste questions without sterilizing. Glad it works now!

Answer (score 2):

Just for future people who might come here if they get this link in a search result:

There are two situations that can cause this and they are both Nginx configurations.

The first is if any of your enabled sites have an IPv6 listen enabled, but others don't, your system can be defaulting to try IPv6 first and it can be picked up. Odd behavior, but it seemed to be the case when I was troubleshooting it and testing for this specifically.

The second is that your access log may tell you that the heap or bucket size is not enough to create a hash. What this means is that Nginx is not able to build a proper "this domain name maps to this server block". Try increasing the heap size (usually 2048 by default, for testing I doubled it to 4096) and the bucket size (usually 64 by default, for testing I doubled to 128).

Ensuring either all server blocks had a listen statement for IPv6 or removing that, as well as adjusting the heap and bucket sizes fixed this scenario for me on a local dev environment.

Comment: where do I set that heap size? I couldn´t find that directive anywhere in /etc/nginx

Comment: @Titus it's been a while but you could try to use `types_hash_max_size 4096;` in the `http {}` server block. You can also find more info [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_names_hash_bucket_size)

Comment: It was a caching problem in my case; but thanks @captbrogers!